# Canvas Responsive - Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I trying let the responsive canvas following this [topic1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862356/fabric-js-resize-canvas-to-fit-screen?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [topic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581460/fabric-js-changes-my-canvas-size-to-300x150-after-initalization?answertab=active#tab-top)

I'm trying to let the responsive canvas for all devices.

I know it's possible but I'm having a tough time finding the solution.

Following the two topics above I tried to set the width and height for the max canvas size in javascript. And in the css for each device a different size to canvas view, even changing the CSS display size actual size defined in javascript must remain

I´m using fabric.js

---

**SOLUTION**

**Note:** stack Overflow view considering width 360px because of the preview in the post

```js
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas ('c');
  canvas.setHeight(600);
canvas.setWidth(800);

  canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://lorempixel.com/500/500/animals', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), { width: 800,height: 600 });
  
  var text = new fabric.Text('Hello', { left: 100, top: 100, fill: 'blue', });
canvas.add(text);
```

```css
 #c{
     border:1px solid red;
     top:22px;
     left:0px;
     height: 100%;
     width: 99%;
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  #c {   -webkit-transform : scale(0.4);
-webkit-transform-origin : 0 0; }
}    

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #c {   -webkit-transform : scale(0.45);
-webkit-transform-origin : 0 0; }
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #c {   -webkit-transform : scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;}
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #c {   -webkit-transform : scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in my question. In [topic1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862356/fabric-js-resize-canvas-to-fit-screen?answertab=votes#tab-top) I found it:

> X4V1 answered Jun 16 '15 at 20:24
>
> I have found a trick to do that without having to copy the canvas.
>   This solution is really close to css zoom property but events are
>   handle correctly.
>
> This is an example to display the canvas half its size:
>
> -webkit-transform : scale(0.5);
>   -webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;

Comment: I think a drawback is that all gets scaled: if an element gets selected, the box with the controls to resize and rotate are also scaled. Probably not what one wants.